# Extending Camunda Admin with a Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, admin, camunda

I'm interesting in extending Camunda Admin UI with my own Plugin. Is it already implemented?

Camunda JIRA says it is implemented in 7.1. See [CAM-1961](https://app.camunda.com/jira/browse/CAM-1961)

There exist at least one interface called [AdminPlugin](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.3/org/camunda/bpm/admin/plugin/spi/package-summary.html), but I could not find any documentation on it or on how such a plugin can be implemented.

Kind regards,

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one plugin point in Camunda Admin, that is used internally to display multiple categories in the System Settings page. This plugin point is called `admin.system` (https://github.com/camunda/camunda-admin-ui/blob/master/client/scripts/pages/systemSettingsGeneral.js#L16-L22)

There is no official support for plugins in Admin yet, that's why it's not documented. If you think that should be changed, you can create a feature request in the [Camunda JIRA](https://app.camunda.com/jira/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa).

Comment: Created an Issue in Camunda JIRA: [CAM-5105](https://app.camunda.com/jira/browse/CAM-5105)